# Can a Twilio Function call a Redis instance in the cloud?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, twilio

I'm trying to call Redis from a Twilio Function (serverless) and I don't see incoming connections in my Redis log.

Is this setup viable?

Sample code follows:

```
const Redis = require('ioredis');
const fs = require('fs');

exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
  const config = Runtime.getAssets()['config.json'].open();

  let redisClientConfig = JSON.parse(config).redisConfig;
  let contactCacheTime = JSON.parse(config).contactCacheTime;

  if (!redisClientConfig) {
    throw new Error('Redis config not set.');
  }

  const redisClient = new Redis(redisClientConfig);

  redisClient.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(`Cannot connect to redis, reason: ${(err.message || err)}`);
  });

  redisClient.getex('mhn-twilio-bot-contact:'.concat(event.contactKey), 'EX', contactCacheTime)
    .then((res) => {
      if (!res) {
        redisClient.setex('mhn-twilio-bot-contact:'.concat(event.contactKey), contactCacheTime, '<CACHED-VALUE>');
      }
      callback(null, { cached: res ? true : false });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      callback(null, { cached: false });
    });

};
```

Comment: Share the details of your setup and code.

Comment: There's no reason it's not viable, but to help we need to see more details. Please share your code and any errors you are getting when you run your code. Thanks!

Comment: Added code to the question. The error is a timeout when redis try to connect.